# Showing and hiding content with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to tab between to different content views using angular. Currently it starts out showing no content, and then toggles between the two views only after clicking on an option.

What I want it to do is show the first view on load, and then let me toggle between the two.

Here is the current code:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Hello there!</h1>
    <p>Push the radio buttons to change the content!</p>
    <form> 
      <label for="first">Show first content</label>
      <input id="first" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="first">
      <br />
      <label for="other">Show other content</label>
      <input id="other" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="other">
    </form>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <p ng-show="content == 'first'">This is the first content!</p>
      <h2 ng-show="content == 'other'">This is the other content!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/er40/pen/NqWjRo

Comment: Set `content = 'first';` in your controller and angular will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ng-init directive to set initial value to first. this code will help:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Hello there!</h1>
    <p>Push the radio buttons to change the content!</p>
    <form> 
      <label for="first">Show first content</label>
      <input id="first" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="first" ng-init="content='first'">
      <br />
      <label for="other">Show other content</label>
      <input id="other" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="other">
    </form>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <p ng-show="content == 'first'">This is the first content!</p>
      <h2 ng-show="content == 'other'">This is the other content!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good simple solution if you just want to stick to straight HTML. It might however be more useful to use a JS controller. I guess this is up to the OP and how much more is involved other than this.

Comment: @user3277733 if you are satisfied with my answer, then please accept my answer.

Comment: Was going to do it earlier, but it said I needed to wait longer! It is done now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could set this initial state in your controller?

**JavaScript** (MyCtrl.js)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.content = 'first';
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="wrap" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello there!</h1>
    <p>Push the radio buttons to change the content!</p>
    <form> 
      <label for="first">Show first content</label>
      <input id="first" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="first">
      <br />
      <label for="other">Show other content</label>
      <input id="other" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="content" value="other">
    </form>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <p ng-show="content == 'first'">This is the first content!</p>
      <h2 ng-show="content == 'other'">This is the other content!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Don't forget to include the controller**

```
<script src="./MyCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your controller definition is in the wrong place. `ng-controller` should be placed in `<div class="wrap">`

Comment: Sorry, try again, I edit the code to put the ng-controller directive in the correct place.

Comment: Thanks, this works well but I am looking to avoid adding any JS (or even an app name) on this. Mukund Kumar provided a good solution above if you are interested yourself.

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution if you're not looking to use a controller...but to be honest, for future, you may want to do this if your functionality requires a bit more logic down the road.

Answer (score 0):

That is because on initiation your model `content` is not set. You need to set it to 'first' if you want that content block to show.

another workaround if you dont want to mess with js is to add another condition for the first comment blocks `ng-show`. Eg show that chunk when content model is not set at all. Like so: http://codepen.io/svdn/pen/wavdgR

Answer (score 0):

Add this to first input:

```
ng-init="content = 'first'"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Sebsemillia "What I want it to do is show the first view on load, and then let me toggle between the two." I understood that, and I think is valid for the user, Also, If I don't answer to anybody, I will never get enough points to can comment another post. I would like, if me answer is not fine for user3277733, I hope that he say to me what does he need to do? Thanks